# how does ping zero works?

Tags: linux, networking

can anybody explain how does `ping 0` works and it translate to `127.0.0.1`.

```
[champu@testsrv ]$ ping 0
PING 0 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.013 ms

--- 0 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.013/0.026/0.039/0.013 ms
```

Comment: You are pinging yourself :P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Special (and AFAICT) slightly under-documented behaviour in [*iputils*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iputils/) `ping`: you ping yourself.

If you `ping 0` this is what happens (heavily edited and commented for clarity):

```
if (inet_aton(target, &whereto.sin_addr)) == 1) {
    // convert string to binary in_addr
}
// inet_aton returns 1 (success) and leaves the `in_addr` contents all zero.

if (source.sin_addr.s_addr == 0) {    
    // determine IP address of src interface, via UDP connect(), getsockname()
}

// special case for 0 dst address
if (whereto.sin_addr.s_addr == 0)
        whereto.sin_addr.s_addr = source.sin_addr.s_addr;
```

`inet_aton()` isn't POSIX, but I'm assuming it copies the behaviour of [`inet_addr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/inet_addr.html) when less than 4 dotted-decimals are being converted. In the case of a dot-less single number, it's simply stored into the binary network address, and `0x00000000` is equivalent to the dotted form `0.0.0.0`.

You can see this if you `strace` (as root):

```
# strace -e trace=network ping  0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 3
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), 
    sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(58056),   
    sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
...
PING 0 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

You can also see the change if you bind to a *specific* interface instead:

```
# strace -e trace=network ping -I eth0  0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 3
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "eth0\0", 5) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), 
    sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(58408),    
    sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.123")}, [16]) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_RAW, ICMP_FILTER,  ...)
[...]
PING 0 (192.168.0.123) from 192.168.0.123 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
```

While 0 may be treated as 0.0.0.0 and a broadcast address in many cases *that's clearly not what ping is doing*. It special-cases this to mean "the primary IP of the interface in question" (with some extra handling for multicast/broadcast cases).

[RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122) §3.2.1.3 explains the behaviour: both 0.0.0.0 and the IP address with the network masked off (the "host number", e.g. 0.0.0.1 in the case of loopback) mean "this host on this network".

> ```
>        (a)  { 0, 0 }
>
>             This host on this network.  MUST NOT be sent, except as
>             a source address as part of an initialization procedure
>             by which the host learns its own IP address.
>
>             See also Section 3.3.6 for a non-standard use of {0,0}.
>
>        (b)  { 0, <Host-number> }
>
>             Specified host on this network.  It MUST NOT be sent,
>             except as a source address as part of an initialization
>             procedure by which the host learns its full IP address.
> ```

At least in the case of 0 or 0.0.0.0 that is how iputils `ping` behaves, other pings and other OSs may behave differently. For example FreeBSD pings 0.0.0.0 via the default route (which I don't think is "correct" behaviour).

`ping 1` or `0.0.0.1` don't quite work as hoped though (not for me anyway, *iputils-sss20101006*).

Comment: @mr.spuratic.. that what I expected.. thanks

Comment: Isn't it technically treating it as 0.0.0.0 and then _subsequently_ special-casing _0.0.0.0_ to mean "the primary IP of the interface"? What happens if you ping 0.0.0.0?

Comment: @Random832 yes, that's correct.