# Connecting to IP 0.0.0.0 succeeds. How? Why?

Tags: networking, tcp, strace

We are serving a port on localhost and want to check in another process if the port is available. Due to a bug in our code, it is actually trying to connect to the IP `0.0.0.0:<port>`, and for some reason it succeeds -- as strace proves:

```
[...]
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(10002), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
[...]
```

What does it mean? Why does it work?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99336/how-does-ping-zero-works/99346

Answer (score 86, accepted):

0.0.0.0 as a target address refers variously to a non-routable host or to “this host” ([RFC 5735 section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735#section-3)). In practice connecting to 0.0.0.0 is, in most scenarios, equivalent to connecting to localhost. Strictly speaking it isn’t valid as a destination address, on the wire ([RFC 1122 section 3.2.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-30)), only as a source address, so the operating system has to ensure that a packet with destination address of 0.0.0.0 doesn’t leave the system as-is. In practice, when the Linux kernel sees a packet with a destination address of 0.0.0.0 (*i.e.* no destination address), [it copies the source address to the destination address](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.9/source/net/ipv4/route.c#L2742), and if the packet doesn’t have a source address either, it sets both to the loopback address. In both cases the packet is “sent out” over the loopback interface, so it never leaves the system.

When binding, “this host” expands to “any address on this host” — so applications commonly accept connections by binding to 0.0.0.0, which means they’ll receive packets addressed to any IPv4 address on the system.

Comment: To extend this answer a little - it means "any IP address on this system, including IPs that have been added after the listening process started"

Comment: localhost is a single address, mostly 127.0.0.1, while 0.0.0.0 means all addresses on this host.

Comment: @rexkogitans localhost is not a single address, but any address in the range 127.0.0.0/8 - i.e. any address from 127.0.0.0 to 127.255.255.255

Comment: @Dezza No, localhost is 127.0.0.1.  127.0.0.0/8 (as you say, a.k.a. 127.0.0.0 through 127.255.255.255) is loopback with most equipment, e.g. documented by [RFC 5735 page 4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5735#page-4).  (Interestingly, some Cisco equipment can assign loopback to any address, but defaults to not supporting loopback at all. Not that this is likely to affect other equipment on the network.)  However, localhost is a name, typically pointing to just to a single address which is 127.0.0.1, and commonly implemented by using a "hosts" file. So I disagree with your attempted correction.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "it isn’t valid as a destination address, only as a source address"?  When mysql server listens at 0.0.0.0, is the address destination or source? Is it not the destination of  a request sent from a mysql client?

Comment: I’m not sure how to clarify. When MySQL listens on 0.0.0.0, that corresponds to the second paragraph of my answer. A client can connect to the server using any valid address for the server, reachable by the client; but not using 0.0.0.0, unless the server is on the same system as the client.

Comment: So you mean a client can't use 0.0.0.0 as destination. How can it be used as a source?

Comment: Where did I say a client *can’t* use 0.0.0.0? I’ve explained what happens when a client connects to 0.0.0.0, which implies that it is possible (even though theory says it isn’t). 0.0.0.0 is used as a source address when the real source address isn’t known, *e.g.* for DHCP requests.

Comment: Does 0.0.0.0  have two completely different meanings? A process specifies its own unknown address to another process not in the same host. A process specifies that it is listening on all the addresses on the local host?